# Wireless programming of MCU in liquid

Tags: microcontroller, wireless

Which methods can be used to program the device in a liquid reservoir (high voltage insulating oil) wirelessly quickly and safely? There will be a distance of 3-5cm between the programmer block and the block in the liquid. A data packet will be sent to install new firmware or just to update various parameters. The transfer process needs to be secure and as fast as possible. Is NFC a suitable method? Which of the communications such as BLE, LoRa, Zigbee should be preferred?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an open dielectric path (nonmetallic casing), any of those will work.  NFC over an inch or two being the most dubious, I suppose, but still well within general capability.

Note that antenna dimensions will be shorter, due to, basically, the index of refraction of the liquid at radio frequencies (n = \$\sqrt{\kappa}\$).  This affects self-resonant antennas most strongly, and lumped-equivalent antennas (like NFC) less strongly.  You'll have to test them yourself -- which I suppose favors external-antenna type modules over integrated ones (that can't be re-tuned at all), and even more strongly favors NFC over UHF comms (simple LC tuning, no VNA required).

If the enclosure is metal, that's a bit of a problem, but if it can be arranged to have a window or slots added around the device, that will do.  Otherwise, communication through solid metal is limited by skin depth, which will require a specialized (custom) communication scheme, and very low bitrates (100s bps, if that?).